# Can i display the first occurrence of a value based on multiple conditions?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an sql query which extracts data similar to the following example:
[image]

What i am trying to acomplish is to display the first occurrence of each role based on the start date. I've added an example in the above picture on the last column.

So the conditions would be:

1. **Skillset 1** must be different than **Skillset 2**
2. If **Skillset 1** and **Skillset 2** contain the first occurrence but they are on different rows,concatenate them
3. If **Skillset 1** is blank but **Skillset 2** contain the required value, display **Skillset 2** (also applies the other way around)

So far I've tried to use a Dax custom column which contains the following piece of code, but it is not what i want:

```
FirstOC = 
var skill1 = IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Table[Skillset 1] ) ),
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            [Project] = EARLIER([project]) &&
            [Skillset 1] = EARLIER([Skillset 1])&&
            [index] <= EARLIER([index])
        )
    ) = 1)
var skill2 = IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Table[Skillset 2] ) ),
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            [Project] = EARLIER([project]) &&
            [Skillset 2] = EARLIER([Skillset 2])&&
            [index] <= EARLIER([index])
        )
    ) = 1)
var date = CALCULATE ( MIN ( Table[Start Date].[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[Index] ) )
return 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
 NOT(ISBLANK( skill1)) && skill1 <> skill2,Table[Skillsset 1],
not(ISBLANK(skill2)) && skill2 <> skill1,Table[Skillset 2]
)
```

Is it doable through **DAX** or even **SQL** ?

Comment: Image is not a better option to show your sample data. to give solution, its always required to play with data, so tabular formatted data is best option. Also exclude columns that are not required for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this following DAX/Measure-

Considering your table name: **concanate**

```
concanate_skillset = 

VAR current_row_skill_1 = MIN(concanate[skillset 1])
VAR current_row_skill_2 = MIN(concanate[skillset 2])
VAR current_row_start_date = MIN(concanate[start date])

VAR find_prev_occurance_skill_1 =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(concanate),
        (concanate[skillset 1] = current_row_skill_1 || concanate[skillset 2] = current_row_skill_1)
            && concanate[start date] < current_row_start_date
    )
) + 0

VAR find_prev_occurance_skill_2 =
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(concanate),
        (concanate[skillset 1] = current_row_skill_2 || concanate[skillset 2] = current_row_skill_2)
            && concanate[start date] < current_row_start_date
    )
) + 0

RETURN IF(find_prev_occurance_skill_1 = 0,current_row_skill_1,"") 
    & IF(
        current_row_skill_1 = BLANK() || current_row_skill_2 = BLANK(),
        "",
        IF(
            find_prev_occurance_skill_1 = 0 && find_prev_occurance_skill_2 = 0, 
            ","
            ,""
        )
    )
    & IF(find_prev_occurance_skill_2 = 0,current_row_skill_2,"")
```

Here is the final output for your sample data-

[image]